# How to install/compile SDL2 C code on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, sdl

I'm currently doing some C programming and I actually want to use the SDL library. I want to build a Small 2D game in C on Linux to sharp my skills a bit.

My issue is I'm not a super **Makefile** user nor library on Linux super user, I just configure things once when on a project and that's it.

So I have some trouble compiling SDL2 programs on UBUNTU 14.04.

I downloaded the latest SDL library from : http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php

Then I installed it with the default step:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After that I can see that there is something in **/usr/include/SDL2** so I guess it is installed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 printf(“SDL test\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

Because I'm still learning Makefiles and SDL I didn't figure it out to make it.

but I found this Makefile to compile the old SDL not the SDL2

```
CPP=gcc   
CFLAGS=-O3 
LDFLAGS=-lSDL -lSDL_mixer #Linker
EXEC=test 

all: ${EXEC}

${EXEC}: ${EXEC}.o
    ${CPP} $(CFLAGS) -o ${EXEC} ${EXEC}.o ${LDFLAGS}

${EXEC}.o: ${EXEC}.c
    ${CPP} $(CFLAGS) -o ${EXEC}.o -c ${EXEC}.c


clean:  
    rm -fr *.o

mrproper: clean
    rm -fr ${EXEC}
```

But this Makefile is not working for me it says that it doesn't know the lSDL_Mixer and other stuff.

How can I build a workable Makefile to compile C program with SDL2 using Makefiles and vim editor.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: SDL Mixer is a *separate* library, it doesn't come with SDL.

Comment: You said `SDL.h` is in `/usr/include/SDL2` but you're including `SDL/SDL.h`, shouldn't that be `SDL2/SDL.h`? Or simply `-I/usr/include/SDL2` to `CFLAGS` and `#include <SDL.h>` which is the standard way.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's a mistake wrote SDL2

Comment: I think @zenith mentioned the answer in his comment. You need to add the `-I/usr/include/SDL2` (or wherever you have it installed) flag to `CFLAGS` if you want to be able to `#include` it IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll go ahead and clean up that Makefile for you.

```
CFLAGS = -O3
LDFLAGS =
appname = test

all: $(appname)
clean:
    rm -f $(appname) *.o
.PHONY: all clean

sdl_cflags := $(shell pkg-config --cflags sdl2 SDL2_mixer)
sdl_libs := $(shell pkg-config --libs sdl2 SDL2_mixer)
override CFLAGS += $(sdl_cflags)
override LIBS += $(sdl_libs)

$(appname): test.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

### Explanation

- Variables in a makefile should be used with `$(...)`, not `${...}`.
- `pkg-config` has an entry for SDL_Mixer, `sdl-config` does not.  `pkg-config` is much more general.
- using `override` with the SDL flags allows you to run something like `make CFLAGS="-O0 -g"` without breaking SDL support.
- This is actually important: the SDL library flags have to be at the end of the command line, in `LIBS`, due to the fact that the GNU linker is sensitive to the order in which libraries are specified.
- You don't need explicit rules for `.c` files, because GNU Make has implicit rules which are just fine.

Note that there are some very important features missing from this makefile.  For example, it won't automatically recompile things when you change your header files.  I would recommend that you use another build system, such as CMake or SCons, which handles this automatically.  You can also do it with Make, but you'd have to paste several arcane lines of code into your makefile.

Comment: Thanks It helped me now it is giving a compiler error at least it compile :). The compiler error : Package SDL2_mixer was not found in the pkg-config search path. But yeah if I remove SDL2_mixer then it compile fine. I guess I also have to install SDL2_mixer... Anyway thanks for your help it helped me to get in the right direction.

Comment: Make sure to install the development version, `libsdl2-mixer-dev` on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sdl2-config` as suggested by the [SDL Linux FAQ](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQLinux) to get the required compiler and linker flags:

```
SDL_CFLAGS := $(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
SDL_LDFLAGS := $(shell sdl2-config --libs)

CFLAGS := $(SDL_CFLAGS) -O3
LDFLAGS := $(SDL_LDFLAGS) -lSDL_mixer
```

It will find the location of your `SDL.h` and return the corresponding flag (e.g. `-I/usr/include/SDL2` in your case) among other flags it deems necessary (e.g. for me it gives `-D_THREAD_SAFE`). And then you can simply `#include <SDL.h>`, which is the standard way to include SDL.