# sdl, sdl2 error: SDL_window (among others) not declared

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

I have played around with `C++` for a while and just recently started to get into `SDL` and `SDL2`.

I was able to get the [dot demo program](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/290187-linux-game-programming-tutorial-1-introduction-first-sdl/) to work.

But other programs, such as [Lazy Foo' Productions's](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/codeblocks/index.php) copied and pasted don't seem to work. 
I have both SDL and SDL2 installed (and uninstalled and reinstalled.)  I am on Ubuntu 15.04 and I have the IDE CodeBlocks linked (`-ISDL2`) 
The errors are `SDL_Window` - `SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED` - `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN` - `SDL_CreateWindow` - `SDL_GetWindowSurface` - `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` and finally, `SDL_DestroyWindow` -- was not declared in this scope.

Also, I include:

```
#include </usr/include/SDL/SDL.h>
#include </usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

I'm pretty sure that I don't need all of that location, but it didn't work without it either. One other note, when I type the `#includes`, CodeBlocks will suggest `SDL2/SDL.h` but not `SDL/SDL.h`.

What am I missing?

I don't think I can put Lazy Foo' code here - I didn't get permission...

Comment: Do you find these files in `/usr/include/SDL` and '/usr/include/SDL2`?

Comment: I now that there are folders for both SDL and SDL2 in /usr/include/.

Answer (score 6):

The code you listed;

```
#include </usr/include/SDL/SDL.h>
#include </usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Why don't you change it to

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

as the first header is where `SDL_CreateWindow` and other SDL2 functions are declared?

Also you don't need to include both SDL and SDL2 headers. Indeed that could very well be the source of your problem as you would only need to include the version you're using.

If you're following the tutorials from lazyfoo's site, you can check if the ones you're following are using SDL1.2 or SDL2 from their table of contents, as the site actually have the tutorials for both versions.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't notice that your platform is a Linux platform. Then it is so much easier to solve your problem. The demo that you followed previously was done using SDL-1.2, whereas the gcc error hinted that you're using SDL-2.0, hence `SDL_CreateWindow` and other undefined errors. You should install SDL-2.0 library and SDL-2.0 development files (which will provide you with the necessary SDL-2.0 headers). You may refer this to SDL-2.0 packages provided by your platform distribution.

As for the compilation, it'll be the same as the tutorial you've followed with a minor change, instead of `gcc sdltest.o -lSDL -o sdltest`, you'll issue `gcc sdltest.o -lSDL2 -o sdltest` to indicate that you're linking your code against SDL2 library.

**EDIT**

A simple SDL program to test your environment. You can use any of the simpler text editor such as `nano` or `gedit` or others to edit this, and run the compilation command above to test your setup.

The simplest way to do this is by copy the code, then from your terminal, issue `cat > sdltest.cpp` and paste the code, then hit [ENTER] and [CTRL-C] to end it. Then you can issue the compilation command as mentioned previously,`g++ sdltest.cpp -lSDL2 -o sdltest`.

Code;

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Window *p;
    SDL_Renderer *w;

    p = SDL_CreateWindow("Game",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,800,640,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    w = SDL_CreateRenderer(p, -1, 0);

    SDL_RenderClear(w);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(w,255,0,0,255);
    SDL_Rect Rect = {220,140,200,200};

    SDL_RenderFillRect(w,&Rect);

    SDL_RenderPresent(w);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(w);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(p);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: He'll need to ask compiler to look for the include files in `/usr/include`. Also, another thing is that you should not put two different versions of the same API included. Use SDL2 and omit the `SDL` inclusion.

Comment: Perhaps if the OP could tell us about his platform, that would make it much easier for us to help him.

Comment: `/usr/include` implies he's on a Unix-like platform, specifically Linux. Also, one of his tags has `linux` in it. :-)

Comment: You are right, silly me. Then it is much easier to solve for his problem. I'll update that in the answer above to reflect this. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Yes I am on linux: Ubuntu 15.04.
I made the change you indicated with the include SDL2/SDLh.  No change.  Lazy Foo's original code uses SDL1.2 in the tuturial for SDL 2.0.  So I changed it to include SDL/SDL.h.  Still no change.  First question, does Lazy Foo Productions have a good reputation for its tutorials?

Comment: You state “You should install SDL-2.0 library and SDL-2.0 development files,” so I looked that part over again.  I know I have a folder in usr/include labeled SDL2 and I am sure I've loaded the library.  Is SDL-2.0 development files different from SDL-2.0 library – how do I make sure I have it loaded?
And finally, you mentioned a change in my compilation – I am not sure what that is.  Is that when you compile it in the terminal?  I think Codeblocks takes care of that for me.

Again, thanks

Comment: @Dan R., SDL2 development files are the headers needed to compile your SDL2 application, while SDL2 libraries are the libSDL2*.so files, such as libSDL2.so, libSDL2_image.so, libSDL2_ttf and so on. Codeblock should be able to find SDL2 headers in /sr/include/SDL2 folder. I would suggest for you to test your environment using a simple editor such as `nano` on your terminal, and to compile it manually using `g++` like I mentioned above. Personally I prefer qt-creator as an IDE for programming, available here; http://download.qt.io/snapshots/qtcreator/. See my updated answer for a test code.

Comment: @Dan R.as per your question about Lazy Foo Productions' reputation on their tutorial, it's good enough for a beginner. You can also get tutorials from youtube, just search for `SDL2 c++ game tutorials`, you'll get plenty of them ranging from beginner to intermediate levels. About your problem, let me know if you still have the problem after following my suggestion above.

Comment: Ok great.  As suggested, I tried the program supplied on the terminal and got all of the same errors.  I think there is something really wrong and that maybe I should uninstall...delete...remove...glare at it....and reinstall.  Thoughts?

Comment: Are the libSDL2.so files supposed to be in the /usr/lib folder?

Comment: Yes if you installed it using your distribution's package manager, the libraries should be installed in `/usr/lib`. Probably you should try to uninstall and reinstall it back using Ubuntu's package manager? You can follow the instructions listed on Lazy Foo' Productions site; http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/index.php

Comment: I've done all this and still not getting anywhere.  Poop.

Comment: Can you list the SDL libraries in /usr/lib and folder to ensure that your system has all the needed SDL2 lib? Also does your system have /usr/include/SDL2 folder?

Comment: List of files:
usr/include/SDL & SDL2
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0
libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4
libSDL2-2.0.so
libSDL2-2.0.so.0
libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.0
libSDL2.a
libSDL2_image-2.0.so
libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0.0.0
libSDL2_image.a
libSDL2_image.so
libSDL2main.a
libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so
libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0

Comment: libSDL2_net-2.0.so.0.0.0
libSDL2_net.a
libSDL2_net.so
libSDL2.so
libSDL2_test.a
libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so
libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0
libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0.10.2
libSDL2_ttf.a
libSDL2_ttf.so
libSDL.a
libSDL_image-1.2.so.0
libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4
libSDLmain.a
libSDL.so

Comment: @Dan R., Your system does have SDL2 libraries and headers. Try this command to compile your test file; `gcc -Wall -o sdl-test sdl-test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2)`. Also, refer here for more information; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876411/how-to-install-compile-sdl2-c-code-on-linux-ubuntu, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iggmjJ_C_C4&list=PL1H1sBF1VAKXMz8kETLHRo1LwnvB08Q2J. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Again, thanks.  And again tons of errors.  Anything else before I reformat and start this ...  err, machine all over?  (I got a second laptop with Win10/ubuntu 15.04 dual boot.  At this point I might wait for that to see if there is a problem with this machine specifically.)

Comment: I guess it might be the best option to wait for the new system to arrive and to test your SDL2 test file there. If everything goes well there, then it is safe to reformat your current system. Cheers.

Comment: I got it!  and it was a stupid mistake.  I was 'seeing' everywhere including here, "-I(as in idiot)SDL2, not -l(small case L)SDL2.  Boy do I feel like a...   Again, thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: @Dan R. Lol, that happens to us all. Glad that you got it resolved.